# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field

Tags: java, class, gson, loader

I am getting the error:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.gson.JsonNull.INSTANCE from a method in a class that is in a jar, Jest-0.0.2.jar. I also have the package com.google.gson loaded using the gradle artifact: compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.1'

All the projects compile fine, but at runtime, I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.gson.JsonNull.INSTANCE from class io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.isJson(JestHttpClient.java:155)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.createJsonStringEntity(JestHttpClient.java:142)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.constructHttpMethod(JestHttpClient.java:117)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:46)

Not sure why this error shows up. I understand that this is possible if there are two separate class loaders. But I am not doing anything special to load multiple class loaders.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. It is not that I was loading two versions of Gson jars, but that another third party Jar, tika-app-1.2.jar, that was actually bundling the package com.google.gson as part of their jar.

It turns out that the version of Jar they had was version 1.7.1 which had a different version of JavaNull.java and JavaElement.java classes.

Comment: How did you resolve the problem? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like JsonNull.INSTANCE is protected or private, and you're trying to access it directly from JestHttpClient, which outside JsonNull's package (com.google.gson).

As for why you're getting it at runtime...if JestHttpClient is a third-party jar, and you didn't compile it yourself, you wouldn't get an error compiling it.  It's also possible that JestHttpClient was compiled against a different version of Gson than the one you're using -- one in which JsonNull.INSTANCE was public.

Comment: I checked the sources for com.google.gson.JsonNull and the above is not the case - public final class JsonNull extends JsonElement {
  /**
   * singleton for JsonNull
   *
   * @since 1.8
   */
  public static final JsonNull INSTANCE = new JsonNull();
indicates that this has been around since version 1.8.

Comment: If I create a new TestNG class as below:

public class TestGsonJsonNull {
 @Test
 public void testJsonNull() {
  String data = "{}";
  JsonElement result = new JsonParser().parse(data);
  return !result.equals(JsonNull.INSTANCE);  
 }
}

within Eclipse, the JsonNull.INSTANCE is marked as "The field JsonNull.INSTANCE is not visible", but if I create a new project within Eclipse, and then create only the gson-2.2.1.jar and the above test code, there are no syntax errors. Also, the same code does not compile outside using the Java compiler.

Comment: Hmmm.  It does sound like you have two versions of the Gson jar around.  I checked the Gson SVN repo, and it [used to be private](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonNull.java?spec=svn772&r=772), but now it's public.  Is it possible to figure out what your classpath is in the first case you mentioned where it's not working?